# How an event (click) can be triggered again and again by another click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, triggers

**FINAL EDIT**

The solution was a framework (Drupal) solution using Drupal behavior attachment : https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors instead of just jquery. 
From here I just attached my triggered action on the widget.

**-----**

**Context description**: Users can vote several times on one or more projects in the limit of XX number of votes. Everytime they vote, I'd like to trigger a refresh button which update a block showing all the votes aggregated in a table. The block then reload the list in the table using an ajax function and this part works great.

Unfortunately for me, the function below is working only once. After the first click which triggers the refresh button, the next "a.vote" clicks made by the user don't trigger the refresh anymore.

```
function refreshtable(){
$("a.vote").click(function(){
    $(".refresh-button").trigger("click");
    //Missing here something saying: do it again and again as far as user clicks;
    });
};
$(document).ready(refreshtable);
```

**My question**: How can I improve this function to make the triggering happens again and again?

**EDIT** : here is the code of the first button supposed to trigger the second one :

```
$('.plus1-widget', context).once('plus1', function(){
    var plus1_widget = $(this);
    plus1_widget.find('.plus1-link').attr('href', function(){ return $(this).attr('href') + '&json=true'; }).click(function(){
      $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function(json){
        if (json) {
          var newWidget = $(json.widget);
          newWidget.hide();
          plus1_widget.replaceWith(newWidget);
          newWidget.fadeIn('slow');
          Drupal.attachBehaviors();
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

There is this: `plus1_widget.replaceWith(newWidget)`, so as @chad and @JasonP suggested it may be related to the document.ready which implicates that the function is triggered only once, when document is ready, right?
 Then after the function is triggered, the document is STILL ready, and maybe it should be ready AGAIN instead. Not sure I get it right.
Please help me understand this.

Comment: And what happens when the refresh-button is clicked ?

Comment: It reloads the block that show the list of votes in a table

Comment: does the refresh button get reloaded as well?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems like yes, please see my edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `a.vote` element you bound the event to gets replaced when you refresh the html, causing the handler to be lost. Try event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.vote', function() {
    $(".refresh-button").click();
});
```

Comment: To make it more clear, @JasonP is saying when the refresh button is clicked and you get new data from the ajax call, the a.vote elements are replaced with new a.vote elements, and your code to bind click handlers to them is only run once, when the document is ready.

Comment: I tried the code, it is not working, not even once like before. I think I see what you are pointing at. I tried with (window).load to check, same behavior..

Comment: So I found a solution by changing the document.ready to a widget attachment using Drupal Behavior attachment system: https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors. Thanks so much for enlighting this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.vote").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".refresh-button").trigger("click");
});
});
```

Comment: ok now it works once, like with my previous code. I think it misses some kind of loop.

Comment: are you replacing the anchor tags after clicking?

Comment: concerning the refresh button, I think the function of the button does that yes (please find my edit in the description above), concerning the a.vote button nope, I don't replace the anchor tag. Should I?